# UploadBlob async triggers System.PlatformNotSupportedException on Microsoft.Azure.Device.client

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub, notsupportedexception

I have a .Net4.8 App which reference a NetStandard library 2.0 which reference the Microsoft.Azure.device.Client 1.25 library.

Most of the functionality are working fine expect when I am trying to call:

```
        _client?.UploadToBlobAsync(blobName, source).Wait();
```

In this case I am getting a:

System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'

The reason is at the:

at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_SslProtocols(SslProtocols value)
at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.HttpClientHelper..ctor(Uri baseAddress, IAuthorizationProvider authenticationHeaderProvider, IDictionary2 defaultErrorMapping, TimeSpan timeout, Action1 preRequestActionForAllRequests, X509Certificate2 clientCert, HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler, ProductInfo productInfo, IWebProxy proxy)
at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.HttpTransportHandler..ctor(IPipelineContext context, IotHubConnectionString iotHubConnectionString, Http1TransportSettings transportSettings, HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler)
at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.InternalClient.UploadToBlobAsync(String blobName, Stream source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.DeviceClient.UploadToBlobAsync(String blobName, Stream source)

This issue seems to have been reported many times from what I can read it should not be there on the .Net framework 4.7.2 and above.

Could you please tell me more about it.

Thanks in advance,
Hak

Comment: Please provide a repro of the problem. With the information provided in the question I was not able to reproduce the problem. In my test I have created a .NET4.8 app with a NetStd2.0 lib that performs UploadToBlob successfully. Please share code that produces the exception. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thanks for your comment after investigation I had a dead link somehow to the 1.23 version which reference the 4.5 .net framework hence not available. weirdly when I got the nugget which was using the 1.25 it installed the 1.23 version which caused this issue.

Comment: @hak can you convert your comment to the answer to this post? Thanks :)